# php exceptions - throw/catch not working across loops

Tags: php, exception, php-5.2

This should so work.   Please tell me I'm doing something wrong.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
try {
  echo "start";
  throw new Exception("test");
  for ($index=0; $index < 1; $index++) {
    echo "loop";
  }
} catch ( Exception $e ){
  echo "caught $e";
}
?>
```

I'm getting an uncaught exception, if I move the throw inside the loop it works fine, but that defeats my purpose.   I could hack in separate try/catch blocks, but thats hackish.

I've tried it on a 5.2.13 and 5.2.17 server.   Current production is at 5.2.17, and no I haven't tested it on 5.3.8 because I'd have to get with my host to upgrade, and retest a lot of code.

Any love?

P.S.
I do know the difference between an exception and an uncaught exception.   But here's the result:

```
start
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'test' in C:\UniServer\www\admin\water_ws\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\UniServer\www\admin\water_ws\test.php on line 4
```

Comment: Seems to catch fine on [viper7 (5.2.15RC3-dev)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KALRDl) and [codepad (5.2.5)](http://codepad.org/WPkjTxnn)… are you sure something else isn't at play here? The fact that you `echo $e` (conversion of Exception to string) which shows similar output to the uncaught case may not help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is not working?  Is it printing "loop" and not "caught test"?

Comment: OP suggests neither (uncaught exception); but I reckon `caught $e` looks a lot like `Fatal error: Uncaught $e`.

Comment: Any chance you have eAccelerator enabled?  It and other opcode caches frequently have well documented issues with exceptions.

Comment: cbuckley - no I'm not sure something else isn't at play, this is one of those wtf errors that just don't smell right.   But the conversion of Exception to a string is a red herring.

Comment: landons - It IS the eAccelerator!   Disabled it and bingo :)  Wanna post it as an answer and I'll promote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As landons suggested, it was eAccelerator's "optimizing" that optimized my catch block away.   Once I disabled eAccelerator it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

why do you echo `$e` object?
try this:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("test");
    for ($index=0; $index < 1; $index++) {
        echo "loop";
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `echo $e;` will invoke the `Exception` class's `__toString()` method which will return a nice summary of the thrown exception.